# How do I convert a list of file paths to their short file path, DOS/8,3 format, using a macro in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, path, filepath, short

I have a list of file paths in cells in Excel that locate to sets of folders, example:

```
**Start:** G:\TSB\Bridge Shared\Bridge Plans\Bridge Plans-SCANNED\2574 35_Long Creek
```

**Want this:** G:\TSB\Bridge~1\Bridge~1\Bridge~1\2574 35~1 (I wrote this by hand so it might not be perfect but hopefully you get what I mean)

I have nearly 3000 file paths listed in Excel but would like them to be displayed in the short file path format, DOS or 8.3 format is what it is called I believe.

Basically I have the folder locations listed in column A in Excel, and I want a macro to run that looks at each individual path and converts it to short path version in column B. There has to be some way to do this automatically and not one by one?

Any help would be appreciated, just can't seem to find anything online to get me started as I am a beginner in VBA.

Comment: What's your code doing? "I need XYZ, can someone do it for me" isn't a valid question to ask on this site. See [ask].

Comment: I want the code to take a list of folder addresses, and convert them from the regular windows file path (example of one is above in the original question), to the short path format which is DOS/8.3 format. I have nearly 3000 paths to convert so I want column A to be the originals, and then spit out the short path version in column B. I don't have a code to post and say "here is what I have so far" because this isn't exactly my forte as stated above. I am just looking for some guidance or example codes so I can understand where to start.

Answer (score 3):

The `FileSystemObject` can help you here. It's not clear whether your paths are files or folders, and whether you want just the folder/file shortname, or the entire path in short name format. I've allowed for either Folders or Files (and I check if they exist before trying to get their path), and I return the full path in short name format.

**EDIT - Adapted to be used as a worksheet function**

You can now use this function in a cell like `B1` with a formula like: `=GetShortPath(A1)`

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetShortPath(path As String) As String

  'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

  Static fso As FileSystemObject
  If fso Is Nothing Then
      Set fso = New FileSystemObject
  End If

  'If the path is a file - Output the full path in 8.3 format
  If fso.FileExists(path) Then
      GetShortPath =  fso.GetFile(path).ShortPath
      Exit Function
  End If

  'If the path is a folder - Output the full path in 8.3 format
  If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
      GetShortPath = fso.GetFolder(path).ShortPath
      Exit Function
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear on that, they are folders not files. So when the path/address is opened it will open the folder in question and the user can look at what they need specifically inside. Will this code still work for a folder and not a PDF (or some other type of actual file)?

Comment: Also, its going to get very tedious to paste the location of the folders in the red quotations, is there a way to have the sub automatically do this by looking at the current column I have, taking the location I listed, and putting it into those red quotations?

Comment: I've changed the routine to a function that you can use in a cell formula

Comment: Maybe I got something wrong here. I was going to show an example why this may lead to problems, however: Using your script, it always outputs the long file path... `?GetShortPath("U:\this is the new folder\this is the new text file.txt")` returns "U:\this is the new folder\this is the new text file.txt" (folder & file do exist)

Comment: @DirkReichel The function works OK for me on existing file or folder paths.

Comment: @DirkReichel Try it against a file on your `C:` drive, or a drive implementing NTFS/FAT32. `GetShortPath("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office")` returns `C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2`. I suspect your `U:` drive is not a Windows drive, and there isn't any DOS version of the file name.

Comment: You are right. `U:` is a hosted network drive. Thanks for the clarification :)